# One shouldn't fail an audit immediately if one clicks on edit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

When one does a review audit on an answer in the Low Quality Review queue that should be deleted because it is spam, and one clicks the `edit` button, one immediately fails this audit.

This should be changed so one only fails the audit, if one *actually commits* any edits because there are sometimes legitimate reasons to click the edit button - e.g. to see the edit history of the answer.

---

Example of when the current behavior does not work at all:

Today I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6710020) that should have been closed because it was a spam answer. But the answer in question was already edited and did read something like this:

> This answer was spam, I removed the contents.

So I clicked the `edit` button to see if the original answer actually was spam ... and failed the audit.

In my opinion the only reasonable action in such a case is to click the `edit` button to *verify*, that the answer actually is spam. If it is spam it should of course be closed. With the current behavior reviewers are encouraged to close *any* already edited answer marked as spam immediately which is certainly not intended.

Comment: @Balder: You do so by clicking the "edited <date>" above the editor's name, not the Edit button.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks - I didn't realize that this is possible. I'll try this out the next time I'm reviewing an already edited answer.

Comment: Or "you can see **[the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27459328/revisions)** for details".

Comment: @TLama: That message is not shown in review. You would have to click the link to the post in order to see it.

Comment: @BoltClock, oh, definitely! That would be an easy review then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If clicking Edit didn't immediately fail an audit, then reviewers would try to edit the content, only to find themselves unable to submit the edit because it wasn't an actual review item to begin with. While this would be a neat passive-aggressive way to waste a robo-reviewer's time, I don't think an honest reviewer would appreciate their time being wasted this way. Remember that the sole purpose of audits is to trap robo-reviewers — to an honest reviewer, it's nothing more than a sanity check, and they'll want to be able to move on to the next, *actual*, review item as quickly as possible.

You should be able to view the revision history of a review item, even an audit, by clicking where it says "edited <date>" above the editor's name in the post. Once you've verified that it is indeed spam, click the appropriate action button. Since you're not trying to edit the post, you shouldn't be clicking Edit at all.

It should be noted however that spam posts should not be edited at all, so you shouldn't have had to check the revision history in the first place. When encountering spam, just flag it as such and move on. When a post with spam flags is deleted, [its contents will be automatically hidden outside of review, even from 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131026/remove-links-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-community-from-spam-offensive-flags/199969#199969), so it is not necessary for anyone to edit out the content.

Comment: @BoltClock `I don't think an honest reviewer would appreciate their time being wasted this way.` This is a very good point. I'll remove the feature request because of this - it would do more harm than good. If your suggestion to access the revision history works I'll accept this answer and consider this question solved.

Comment: Why would a robo-reviewer click edit? They're a robo-reviewer; they don't want to think about anything. Editing requires a great deal of thinking.

Comment: @jpmc26: Exactly. Since only an honest reviewer would even try to click Edit, it's even more of a slap in the face for them to find themselves unable to submit what would have otherwise been a legitimate edit.

Comment: @BoltClock Hm. I guess the other side of that, though, is that if Edit immediately passed the audit, a robo-reviewer could abuse that really easily. A lot of them *would* click Edit and then just cancel if the review was real. Ugh. Review audits are such a broken system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21388076 ... I just wanted to see the source to determine why it was badly formatted; I _never_ wanted to approve this post. Can you lift the ban?

Comment: @Cœur: Done now.