# Failed audit after attempting to edit a question

Tags: bug, edits, review-audits

I recently failed an audit in the Late Answers queue.  I attempted to edit the answer and was directed to a screen that read "This post cannot be edited because it has been deleted."  When I clicked the "back" button on my browser, the system told me I had failed the audit.

However, I never clicked "No Action Needed" or any of the other action buttons.  It is as if the system registered "No Action Needed" without my input.

Any insight as to why this happened or how it can be fixed?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the failed audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18043857

It is a poorly formatted code-only answer, but it does not strike me as abuse or spam.  I tried to edit it and was navigated to the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47108196/edit

Comment: The post was probably considered unsalvageable. As such, editing is a fail. There is no editing that can convert a spam post into a good one, for example.

Comment: I don't think that's a bug but intentional. You took the wrong action on the audit.

Comment: It was not obvious spam or abuse.  Perhaps a "very low quality" answer.  I was going to decide whether or not to flag or comment after formatting the code.  Should editing be an automatic fail before I have the chance to take decisive action by clicking "Done" or "No Action Needed"?

Comment: If you are going to flag, do not bother editing. Your edits need to go through the review queue. What's the point in editing something that you believe needs deleting?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [One shouldn't fail an audit immediately if one clicks on edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283179/one-shouldnt-fail-an-audit-immediately-if-one-clicks-on-edit)

Comment: A fair point.  I have never flagged after editing, so I can see why the system would consider editing a fail when flagging was appropriate.  Still, shouldn't the system wait until one of the "decision" buttons is pressed before registering a fail.

I have tried to find the audit in my review history, but I can't find it.  Maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I've looked in your review history and couldn't find it either. I guess that since the post is deleted, we the little people can't see the review either. Read the answer in the question linked by Bryan, it addresses your "decision" point.

Comment: It was definitely on SO.  Maybe the audit was never recorded.  Thanks for all of your inputs.  I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: @Tom are you sure it was that queue and you got a failure notice? You've had 3 audits in the last 2 days for that queue and passed them all...

Comment: I am 90% sure it was the Late Answers queue, but it could have been the First Posts queue.  The strange thing is that I did not get the normal audit failure notice.  But when I clicked back from the "this post cannot be edited..." I got a message that said "Audit failed 32 secs ago."  I was as if I was looking at review history.  Still, I cannot find the audit in my history which leads me to believe this was a bug.  Here is the failed audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18043857

Comment: [That failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18043857) has a different reviewer than you.

Comment: My memory is poking me. I think there is a concurrency problem with audits that sometimes two happen at the same time and you might see an audit failure on the same content that someone else caused.