# Why does a review ban occur when I click "edit", instead of "save"?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review-queues, review-suspension

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently.
>  Come back in 2 days to continue
>   reviewing.

I got the above ban today when I clicked the "edit" button. Isn't the ban supposed to happen if I do "Save" for the post?

I am surprised, why does Stack Overflow need to count the number of times "edit" is clicked, instead of "save"?

"Save" will make the action complete!

Comment: `the ban is suppose to be happen if i do save for the post?` I realize English might not be your first language, but I can't make any sense of that. Can you clarify please?

Comment: While reviewing i clicked edit button for a "perfect answer post". I didn't edit that post. But i got the banned notice. I should be banned only if i have done an edit to that post and save it. Here stackoverflow is counting number of edit clicks too ?

Comment: As a side note: a review ban is temporary. After a while, you will be able to review again. _If_ you continue to review, you may want to consult the the guidelines for reviewing. They are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/168333).

Comment: But why would you _click on edit button for a "perfect answer post"_ ?

Comment: @DebanjanB I think they only call it a "perfect answer" now that they know they should not have tried to edit.

Comment: Can I ask what edit you felt you could have made to that post?

Comment: I don't understand why trying to edit a positive scoring answer would cause a failed First Posts review _at all_, regardless of when the button was pressed. An edit is not a flag suggesting the content should be removed, nor is it a downvote or any other form of censure. In this review context, to me pressing the Edit button means "the answer does not need be deleted but I can give it a little polish".

Comment: The answer could certainly be improved: the first letter of the sentence is not capitalised, the last character should be a ':' not a '.', and the word 'encryption' might be expanded on/clarified. The missing explanation about why and how the suggested SQL would resolve the error in the question could be added.

Comment: FYI, this was a bug - I lifted your review ban the day you posted this, but just came across this report now. Details on the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

I think you mean that the ban should not happen until you actually complete your edit.

But then - you would do a lot of editing work, then clicked "Save" on the edit, and THEN the system would tell you you were banned.
That would be a bad user interface - you'd do the editing work, then be told not to. Also, it leaves one with the question - should this edit be applied? Since apparently "edit" was the wrong choice, it might be better not to apply the edit.

Better to give the review ban the moment you click "edit". That way, it saves us all from unnecessary work.

Comment: User will be always in a choice that he can cancel/discard his edits any time before save. Save will only make the action complete.

Comment: @syam It is just one of many inconsistencies in SO review queues. Probably that is why you are allowed to fail more than one audit before being banned. It is been like this for years and is unlikely to be fixed.

Comment: @Ivan The review system is far from perfect. But this particular part - I consider it the lesser of two evils. Imagine making a big edit, clicking "Save", and THEN be told that you were doing reviewing wrong. The edit should not be applied in this case... so you'd have done all that editing for naught, on top of the review ban. That's just adding insult to injury.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Some people click "edit" immediately when they see something that can be improved and are editing posts as they read it. If they realize the post was really bad, edit is cancelled and post is reported. With current system you click "edit" before you were even able to read the post and get a failed audit, even though you would never actually complete this edit. So it fails either way, just for different cases.

Comment: @Ivan Yeah, that's why I called it the lesser of two evils. Just realized that it's [been discussed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283179/812149).