# Non-spam, non-rude answer deleted as spam/rude?

Tags: support, review-audits, spam

Failed an audit for https://stackoverflow.com/a/77660440/367865. It seems to have been deleted as spam/rude, I'm not sure it should've been categorized like that. The link is questionable, but that answer itself stands after removing the link.

Comment: It's spam. The link near the beginning is titled "C#" but has nothing to do with C# and all to do with pushing a website. The answer was likely AI generated, and regardless, the spammy link nullifies all.

Comment: But the link makes it spam. So what if the answer stands without the link?

Comment: [Is it ever appropriate to edit and remove potential spam links?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408136)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It has a spam link on C#. That link has been used to spam 20 posts and that user used it in 4 of those posts before they were destroyed.

We don't edit out spam links posted by spammers, we just delete the post and destroy the user. Such posts even without links are low quality, almost always plagiarised or LLM-generated and not useful.